# control cursor location in text file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void level (int n , FILE*f , FILE*f2)
{
    int i=0 ;
    int k=0 ;
    for (i=0 ; i< n ; i++ )
    {
        if (k != '\n')
        {
            k=fgetc(f) ;
            fputc(k,f2) ;

            while ( k!='\\'&& k!=EOF && k!='\n' )

            {
                k=fgetc(f) ;
                fputc(k,f2) ;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            break ;
        }
    }
}


void menu (int n , FILE*f , FILE*f2)
{
    char ch [1000] ;
    do
    {
        level(n,f,f2) ;
        fputc('\n',f2) ;
    }
    while (fgets(ch,1000,f)!= NULL ) ;
}

int main()
{

    FILE*f=NULL ;
    FILE*f2=NULL ;

    f = fopen("text.txt","r+") ;
    f2= fopen("t.txt","w+") ;

    menu(5,f,f2) ; 
    fclose(f);
    fclose(f2);
    return 0;

}
```

The file f contains lines. Every line is in this form `text1\text2\...\..` The file f2 is empty, when the function `level` reach the end of one line , the function `menu` doesn't "get" the next line but it gets the line after the next one , i need a solution please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're reading the next line inside the `menu` function, your `level` function cannot read it again. The best solution (without changing much code) is to have the `level` function accept a char[] parameter containing the already-read line, instead of the file from which to read.

You will also need to change your `do ... while` loop into a `while ...` loop inside the `menu` function.

```
void level (int n , char* s , FILE*f2)
{
    int i=0 ;
    char k=0 ;
    for (i=0 ; i< n ; i++ )
    {
        if (k != '\n')
        {
            k=*(s++) ; // get char from string
            fputc(k,f2) ;

            while ( k!='\\'&& k!=0 && k!='\n' )

            {
                k=*(s++) ; // get char from string
                fputc(k,f2) ;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            break ;
        }
    }
}


void menu (int n , FILE*f , FILE*f2)
{
    char ch [1000] ;
    while (fgets(ch,1000,f)!= NULL )
    {
        level(n,ch,f2) ;
        fputc('\n',f2) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: @satrter I edited my answer with some code. I didn't test it, but I made only a few modifications, so it should work.

Comment: I did not check for other errors/problems that your code might have. The only other thing I noted is that this version handles better the case that `f` is empty.